# My 2011 June CTP Entity Framework EDMX is crashing the designer now that I installed Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I had an EDMX using June 2011 CTP and it was working fine. Now I've installed VS 2012 and it's crashing the designer

Message:

> Method not found: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1
>    
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.
>   GetPrimitiveTypes(Double)'.

Any idea?

Comment: Cant you just regenerate the EDMX using EF5 ?

Comment: @StefanP., I have hundreds of tables and table valued functions. That will not be feasible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.GetPrimitiveTypes(Double)` did not exist in EF June 2011 CTP while it exists in .NET Framework 4.5. Uninstall the June CTP and things should work - there have not been much significant changes to the artifacts (csdl, ssdl and msl) so your edmx file should continue to work. Not sure why you contintue to use the CTP while there have been a number of releases (Beta, RC) **including RTM** since then.